# Give a name for a product sale using express checkout

Tags: paypal

I am moving my "checkout using paypal" implementation from REST to classic. With REST Payment, I could specify items with name, `"name": constants["name"]` in my Python code below.

I want to **specify individual items with names and SKUs** with express checkout. Does express checkout not allow items? Its meant for a payment for services rendered, but having item names makes the bill much more **convenient and useful** for the user even if its just one item.

---

My SDK document says these are required for an express checkout:

```
Required Kwargs
---------------
* PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT
* PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION
* RETURNURL
* CANCELURL
```

Python snippet for creating an itemized bill with REST API:

```
"transactions": [{
                "item_list": {
                    "items": [{
                        "name": constants["name"],
                        "sku": constants["sku"],
                        "price": constants["amount"] ,
                        "currency": "AUD",
                        "quantity": 1
                    }]
                },
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "AUD",
                    "total": constants["amount"]
                },
                "description": constants["description"]
            }]
```

This action returns a Paypal page where user is shown the items and is allowed to pay, and which would return me to my site to execute the payment

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout does not require cart information but you can definitely provide it if you want to, either before *or after* the user logs into PayPal to approve.

To provide cart details before the user logs into PayPal, send them in SetExpressCheckout. But the Express Checkout flow was designed to support a merchant getting the buyer's approval earlier in a checkout flow then "upselling" the buyer (to determine shipping costs, add more items, etc) upon their return to the site. In this case the final cart wouldn't be settled until the DoExpressCheckout() API call that makes the actual payment -- so you can send (or override) the cart contents on that API too.

See the "Payment Details Item Type Fields" section of:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/
and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/ 
... for the specific field names to use in whichever API you choose to provide them. In particular there is no sku field; you will have to put sku in the DESC or CUSTOM fields.